# How to check if 2 different values are from the same list and obtaining the list name

Tags: python

** I modified the entire question **

I have an example list specified below and i want to find if 2 values are from the same list and i wanna know which list both the value comes from.

```
   list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
   list2 = ['f','g','h','i','j']

   c = 'b'
   d = 'e'
```

i used for loop to check whether the values exist in the list however not sure how to obtain which list the value actually is from.

```
for x,y in zip(list1,list2):
   if c and d in x or y:
     print(True)
```

Please advise if there is any work around.

Comment: You could take each row, `split` it by `,`s and get the last part which is the size to make a comparison with `size.value`. It would be helpful if you could show your present code.

Comment: @Madhoolika sorry i was just editing to include my current code. Please let me know if you can advise me on any logic

Comment: There is nothing built into Python that is going to know that "W US" is equivalent to "Wide" or "XL" is equivalent to "X-Large."  You are going to have to identify all the ways your data uses different texts for the same meaning and code specific tests or translations to match them.  That means you also have to decide what the possible meanings are.  For example, you have to decide whether "10 W" and "10 M" are the same or different.

Comment: @DennisSparrow Let me know try to outlay the various combinations in a separate variable so that the output values compares them and identifies them as similar ones. Thanks Dennis !!

Answer (score 0):

First u might want to inspect the distribution of values and sizes where you can improve the result with the least effort like this:

```
df_inspect = df.copy()
df_inspect["size.value"] = ["size.value"].map(lambda x: ''.join(y.upper() for y in x if x.isalpha() if y != ' '))
df_inspect = df_inspect.groupby(["size.value"]).count().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Then create a solution for the most occuring size category, here "Wide"

```
long = "adasda, 9.5 W US"
short = "9.5 Wide"

def get_intersection(s1, s2): 
    res = ''
    l_s1 = len(s1)
    for i in range(l_s1):
        for j in range(i + 1, l_s1):
            t = s1[i:j]
            if t in s2 and len(t) > len(res):
                res = t
    return res

print(len(get_intersection(long, short)) / len(short) >= 0.6)
```

Then apply the solution to the dataframe

```
df["defective_attributes"] = df.apply(lambda x: len(get_intersection(x["item_name.value"], x["size.value"])) / len(x["size.value"]) >= 0.6)
```

Basically, get_intersection search for the longest intersection between the itemname and the size. Then takes the length of the intersection and says, its not defective if at least 60% of the size_value are also in the item_name.